# '>': signed/unsigned mismatch. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++

```
std::string text;
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // Gets the console handle.
    PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpScreenInfo = new CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO(); // Creates a pointer to the Screen Info pointing to a temporal screen info.
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, lpScreenInfo); // Saves the console screen info into the lpScreenInfo pointer.
    COORD NewSBSize = lpScreenInfo->dwSize; // Gets the size of the screen

    int choice{};
    
    do
    {
       
        if (NewSBSize.X > text.size())
        {

            int newpos = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newpos; i++) std::cout << "ARES\n"; // Prints the spaces

            int newpos1 = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newpos; i++) std::cout << "MENU\n"; // Prints the spaces
            
            int newpos2 = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newpos; i++) std::cout << "Select one of the following options by pressing 1, 2 or 3:\n"; // Prints the spaces

            int newpos3 = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newpos; i++) std::cout << "1. Activate Virus\n"; // Prints the spaces

            int newpos4 = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newpos; i++) std::cout << "2. Program Information\n"; // Prints the spaces

            int newpos5 = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
            
            for (int i = 0; i < newpos; i++) std::cout << "3. Exit\n"; // Prints the spaces

            std::cin >> choice; 
            
            switch (choice)
            {
                
            case 1:
                
                int newpos = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.

                for (int i = 0; i < newpos; i++) std::cout << "Infection Initiated. Press any key to continue . . .\n"; // Prints the spaces
                std::cin.ignore();
                system("CLS");
                Ares();
                
            case 2:
                
                int newposi = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.

                for (int i = 0; i < newposi; i++) std::cout << "Program Information loading. Press any key to continue . . .\n"; // Prints the spaces
                std::cin.ignore();
                system("CLS");
                ProgramInfo();
                
            case 3:
                
                int newposh = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.

                for (int i = 0; i < newposh; i++) std::cout << "Ending Operations. Press any key to continue . . .\n"; // Prints the spaces
                std::cin.ignore();
                system("CLS");
                menu();
                
            default:
                
                int newposa = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.

                for (int i = 0; i < newposa; i++) std::cout << "Invalid input! Press any key to continue . . .\n"; // Prints the spaces
                
            }

        }
        
    } 
    while (choice < 1 or choice > 3);
```

This is the relevant code where I'm getting the error. If you need to see more of my code, let me know and I'll add it.

I've looked on the internet for a solution and have found similar issues to mine, but none of those repair jobs did anything to solve the problem. Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post the exact error message. Which solutions did you find, so that we can understand what didn't work?

Comment: Please also read [example]. Actually read it. Then do it. Please.

Comment: I would assume that `NewSBSize.X` is an `int`. `std::string().size()` returns `size_t`, which is likely the source of your problem. Since you neither posted the relevant definitions, nor the exact error message, it's only my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> signed/unsigned mismatch. How do I fix this?

Cast narrower to wider.  Considering negative values first if *unsigned* type is wider.

If relative widths not certain, handle negative values first.

---

`NewSBSize.X` is [apparently](http://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Fwinstruct%2Fconsole_screen_buffer_info.htm) a `short`, a *signed* type.

`text.size()` is a [`size_t`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/), an *unsigned* type.

If `NewSBSize.X` was unexpectedly negative, `NewSBSize.X > text.size()` is logically false, so pedantically fail that case.

```
if (NewSBSize.X >= 0 && ....
```

Then converted the `short` to its *unsigned* counterpart - or its *unsigned* promoted counterpart.  The cast here imparts **no** value change to `NewSBSize.X` and the following unsigned compare occurs based on the wider of two unsigned types.

```
... (unsigned) NewSBSize.X > text.size()
```

Altogether

```
if (NewSBSize.X >= 0 && (unsigned) NewSBSize.X > text.size()) {
```

---

If code can insure `NewSBSize.X >= 0`, then simplify to the below.
Warning: micro-optimization is evil.

```
if ((unsigned) NewSBSize.X > text.size()) {
```